# Can NAPI polling mode for NIC be enabled in user-mode application code instead of setting kernel variables?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've just found that there is NAPI in linux kernel which may be used to **poll** events from NIC instead of getting interruptions with context switches and other expensive things. It may be useful for highload systems.

I found an article about it which says that I can enable polling mode for NIC. But the problem is that I can't for some reason. I'm trying to figure out the relations between NAPI, poll/epoll/etc functions to understand is there any way to enable that polling from user-mode level instead of setting kernel variables.

I know that there are some functions like poll/epoll/etc which may be used to read from resources (network sockets) when they are ready.

I have several questions and I'll be glad to get answers from people with knowledge.

1. Is there any way to enable polling from NIC instead of interruptions from user-mode code? Or the only way to do it is to set a kernel variable?
2. I found a question here on SO says that user-mode functions (poll/epoll/etc) under the hood call a driver's function named poll.  So, when I'll use poll/epoll in user-mode looks like I'll work with driver's function. But I'm not sure about interruptions. Will they gone? In my head it's like they are here to give information to a kernel about new packets to read. How the kernel will know about new packets if there are no interruptions?
3. Am I correct that setting kernel variables to poll NIC instead of waiting for (and handling) interruptions is not the same that using poll/epoll functions in user-mode? In my head there is the next high-level algorigth of work:

**with interruptions:**

- Packet went to a NIC.
- NIC calls a hardware interruption to handle that packet.
- Blocked .Read(fd) calls in user-mode is unblocked and data may be read.

**with kernel polling:**

- Packet went to a NIC.
- Another one packet went.
- And one more.
- CPU on some interval polls information from a NIC.
- Blocked .Read(fd) calls in user-mode is unblocked and data may be read.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand NAPI polling. The "polling" is only performed during heavy load in order to eliminate repetitive & wasteful exit-interrupt-mode-and-then-immediately-handle-another-interrupt. There is no "waiting" involved. Userspace cannot possibly be involved in such a scheme. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574203/regarding-napi-implementation-in-linux-kernel

Comment: "*I know that there are some functions like poll/epoll/etc ...*" -- You're probably misunderstanding these syscalls. "Poll" in this case does not mean "repeatedly interrogate", but rather "survey" or "canvas", as in take a *poll* of likely voters before an election. These syscalls can still be event-driven and efficient, unlike a repetitive sampling that waits for a change in state.